# Swift / Firebase: Cancel downloading an image?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following basic code implemented to download an image from Firebase. The function is called from within a UICollectionViewCell. There are cases when a user might scroll quickly past the cell and in those cases, I would like to cancel the .getData download task if it has not yet returned. **Is there a way to cancel .getData?**

```
private func downloadImage(path: StorageReference, handler: @escaping (_ image: UIImage?) -> ()) {
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: path) {
            handler(cachedImage)
        } else {
            path.getData(maxSize: 27 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
                if let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    handler(image)
                    imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: path)
                } else {
                    handler(nil)
                    guard let error = error else { return }
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you capture your Firebase Storage operations as properties, you can call methods on them to pause, resume, or cancel them. For example:

```
let download = path.getData(maxSize: 27 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
    if let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) {
        handler(image)
        imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: path)
    } else {
        handler(nil)
        guard let error = error else { return }
        print(error)
    }
}

download.pause()
download.resume()
download.cancel()
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files?authuser=0#manage_downloads

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!